# change ajax url based on value of select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form with a select box with three selections

```
<select id="tool" name="tool">
    <option value="option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option3</option>
</select>
```

Each selection has its own php file

- option1.php
- option2.php
- option3.php

Based on the selection I would like for the Ajax url to change to the respective php file

Ajax part

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "option1.php",
```

Comment: What results do you get with your current approach?  Do you need to complete your current approach?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery **[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** method

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: $('#tool').val() + ".php",
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you call ajax when an option is selected? :

```
$('#tool').change(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: $('#tool option: selected').val() + '.php',
      //the rest of the code
   });
});
```

Comment: why so complex ? `#tool option: selected` instead of just .val(); ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="tool" name="tool">
    <option value="option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option3</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(function(){
      $('#tool').bind('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val() + ".php"; 
          $.ajax({
                  url: url,
                  data: data,
                  ....
          });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Question is not about to redirect!

Comment: Sumit thanks for notice.
is it better now? The idea is the same to select the URL you need and then do whatever you whant. isn't it?

Comment: Cool! but it was confusing to users :)

Comment: (Y) - will try better next time!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use $.get() which is much simpler

```
 $('#tool').change(function(){
       var url = $(this).val();
          $.get(url,function(data){
              //load your data to any DOM element
               $( ".result" ).html( data ); 
          });
     });
```